# Show / Hide elements - move to top of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using jquery to toggle the hiding and showing of some divs.

This works fine until one of the divs expands off screen. What I'd like to do is scrollup so the div is at the top of the screen.

This is the code I'm using :

```
$('.slider').hide(800);
$('a#show').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.slider')
    $('.slider').not(elem).hide();
    elem.toggle();
});
```

I've also created a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bMJ79/5/)** showing the issue. Clicking on section 2 expands past the bottom of the screen.

Ideally I want this to scrollup so section2 is at the top of the screen.

I've added this to after `elem.toggle();` and it does sort of work.

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: elem.offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bMJ79/6/)**

The issue I have with this is the scrollup frequently scrolls partway into the div and not just to the top.

Can anyone advise how I get this to only scroll to the top of the current div and not to partway into it.

**** UPDATE ****
Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bMJ79/11/)** showing the partial scrolling issue.

Click on Section 1, it will open, scroll down to section 2 and click on it.

it will open part way into the DIV.

How do I sort that ?

** **FOLLOWUP** **

This only seems to be an issue if I have timings in the code :

```
   $('.slider').not(elem).hide(600);
        elem.toggle(600);
```

The above has the issue. yet the following works:

```
   $('.slider').not(elem).hide();
        elem.toggle();
```

but lacks the nice transition. Any way to get both working ?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me as you want it to. How can I reproduce the "scrolling partway into it"?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/bMJ79/7/

Comment: @colburton - original post updated with new fiddle and example of how to replicate issue. Thx

Comment: See new edit to my answer for the fix. If you don't like the waiting I've put in, there may be a way to work out the offset before the first one closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you described your updated code seems to work, the page does scroll to the top of the div you have chosen. However if you wanted the bottom of the div at the bottom of the page, so that it scrolls all the way, you can find the height of the div and window, and work out the scrolltop value from that using this code:

```
scrollTop: elem.offset().top + $(elem).height() - $(window).height()
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bMJ79/9/)

**EDIT:** This is happening because you work out the offset of the second div, then close the first div which changes the position of the second one. You can workaround this by waiting for he first div to close before working out the next offset to scroll to.

```
setTimeout(function(){$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: elem.offset().top
}, 1000);}, 600);
```

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bMJ79/12/)

Comment: Original post updated with new fiddle and example of how to replicate issue. Thx

Comment: Thanks that works, but does add a delay. Is there anyway around that ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know exactly how to do that, but you will need to work out the offset of the div when all others are closed, then scroll to that value while the others are being hidden/shown.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think with a bit of tweaking on the timings this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  $('.slider').not(elem).hide();
    elem.toggle();
```

with

```
$('.slider').not(elem).slideUp(200);
elem.slideToggle(500);
```

Comment: Original post updated with new fiddle and example of how to replicate issue. Thx